# What encoders/decoders/muxers/demuxers/parsers/filters do I need to enable in FFMpeg for converting an mp4 video to a gif?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am building FFmpeg with custom options to reduce the final size of apk file on android. I want just convert a mp4 file to a gif.
Following is my options specified

```
 --disable-everything
 --enable-decoder=mpeg4,mpegvideo,aac,gif,h264
 --enable-parser=aac,mpeg4video,mpegaudio,mpegvideo,gif,h264
 --enable-demuxer=mpegvideo,aac,mov,gif,h264
 --enable-muxer=mp4,gif,mov,h264
 --enable-protocol=file
 --enable-encoder=mpeg4,mov,gif,h264
 --enable-filter=scale,fps,copy,palettegen,vflip,paletteuse,crop
```

What other options do i need to add to successfully run this command?

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "fps=15,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos" -pix_fmt rgb24 output.gif
```

or this command

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 output.gif
```

After I added module into Android Studio I run FFmpeg command.
Iam getting this error:

```
2020-06-21 12:16:09.883 8871-9102/com.example.myapplication W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7088243f40] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
2020-06-21 12:16:09.885 8871-9102/com.example.myapplication W/mobile-ffmpeg: Incompatible pixel format 'rgb24' for codec 'gif', auto-selecting format 'rgb8'
2020-06-21 12:16:09.885 8871-9102/com.example.myapplication E/mobile-ffmpeg: Output pad "default" with type video of the filter instance "Parsed_scale_1" of scale not connected to any destination
2020-06-21 12:16:09.885 8871-9102/com.example.myapplication E/mobile-ffmpeg: Error reinitializing filters!
2020-06-21 12:16:09.885 8871-9102/com.example.myapplication E/mobile-ffmpeg: Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
2020-06-21 12:16:09.886 8871-9102/com.example.myapplication E/mobile-ffmpeg: Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

I also tried to include FULL library and it that case everything worked as expected.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not an answer, but `-pix_fmt rgb24` seems wrong to me for writing a GIF, because GIF is 8-bit palette based. I don't know `ffmpeg` that well but would have expected `rgb8`. I may be wrong, I have been before.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.